# How to avoid losing your work on the PTO's web based application system

Tags: uspto, application, web

I'm using the USPTO's EFS-WEB, and after spending an hour adding documents to a new application, I had to take a break. I wasn't active for an hour and my application disappeared completely. Is this normal? Is there any way to save it? Also, is it possible to work on two applications at once? (I'm a registered user.)

Comment: I have not been on it that long. I find it helpful to create all the documents and put them together in a folder and make sure the names are all EFS-legal before I start. It is an unforgiving interface.

Comment: Turns out you can save your work, but only just before you pay, so not very useful.

Comment: Unfortunately it is a difficult to use system.  I use it nearly everyday as a patent attorney and I cannot wait for them to update/upgrade the system.  However, I am not holding my breath for fixes anytime soon.

Answer (score 1):

If you are registered user you can save your work before submission. See the [EFS-Web Quick Start documentation](https://www.uspto.gov/sites/default/files/documents/Quick%20Start%20Guide%20DOCX%20Intake_3.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

The file can only be saved after payment.

Comment: One sentence answers are frowned upon. Any way you could expand the answer? Perhaps link to the page that describes the policy?